# How to add maven dependencies in java build path

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build

I don't know what happen to my project, "maven dependencies" from JAVA BUILD PATH has been removed.I am getting 100s of error please help me to re-add these jars? Tried many methods.

Comment: try mvn eclipse:eclipse on command line and refresh your project

Comment: Maybe you removed the "Maven nature" from your project. A maven enabled project (aka with Maven nature) is generally marked with an "M" at the top-level Folder.  You can right click on a Java project and click `Configure-Convert to maven project`. Mixing eclipse internal usage and mvn eclipse:eclipse command line usage should be avoided as these modes are not compatible [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061048/how-does-the-m2e-eclipse-plugin-interact-with-eclipse)

Comment: tried did not worked,Any way i delete eclipse and download new again and working fine.I am wonder why people voting down this question. :-|

Answer (score -4):

start your command with mvn eclipse:clean

Comment: after that call mvn eclipse:eclipse

Comment: You might want add the same to answer